# How to deploy docker container to Cloud Foundry?

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

My application is comprised of two separate docker containers. One being a Grails based web application and second being a RESTful Python Flask application. Both docker containers are sitting on my local computer. They are not hosted on docker hub. They are proprietary and I don't want to host them publicly.

I would like to try Cloud Foundry to deploy these docker containers and see how it works. However, from the [documentation](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/adminguide/docker.html#push-docker) I get a sense that Cloud Foundry doesn't support deploying docker containers sitting on a local machine.

**Question**

1. Is there a way to deploy docker containers sitting on a local computer to CloudFoundry? If not, what is a way to securely host the containers somewhere from CF can fetch them?
2. Is CloudFoundry capable of running a docker container that is a Python Flask application?

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to not use Docker images, and just push your code directly, one of the nice features of CF.  PCF comes with a python buildpack which should automatically detect your Flask app.

Another option would be run your own trusted docker registry, push your images there, and then when you push your app, tell it to grab the images from your registry.  If you google "cloud foundry docker registry" you get the following useful results you should check out:

- https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/docker-registry-boshrelease
- http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/adminguide/docker.html#caveats
- https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/opsguide/docker-registry.html